# Can I listen for Eddystone beacons when my app is not running?

Tags: android, google-play-services, eddystone

With [Google's new Eddystone standard](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/07/lighting-way-with-ble-beacons.html?linkId=15518168) they will be providing support for android in Google Play services [Nearby Api](https://developers.google.com/nearby/).  Can we register for eddystone beacons and have our app receive an intent even if the app is not running?

Comment: Hard to say—neither the updated Nearby API, nor any documentation is available at the moment. I would expect them to implement that, but that's just speculation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to do exactly this using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), which has full support for [Eddystone](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-support.html).

The mechanism for background launching of your app works the same way on Eddystone as it does for other kinds of beacons supported by the library.  You use a `RegionBootstrap` object in a custom `Application` class.  You can read details about how this works [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html).

The only difference with Eddystone is that you have to set up a `BeaconParser` that decodes the Eddystone-UID frame, and then set up a `Region` that will match your Eddystone namespace id:

```
public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = ".MyApplicationName";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "App started up");
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        // Detect the main identifier (UID) frame:
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));

        // wake up the app when a beacon matching myEddystoneNamespaceId is seen 
        myEddystoneNamespaceId = Identifier.parse("0x2f234454f4911ba9ffa6");
        Region region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", myEddystoneNamespaceId, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
        // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
        // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.  
        regionBootstrap.disable();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
        // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
       // Don't care
    }        
}
```

Comment: Sounds like this still requires that application to be running - i.e. still have its process.  It appears if the user where to force stop the app, would it not receive the callback because the application would not be running.

Comment: Yes, the process is technically running in the background, at least to look for beacons.  However,  it will not show up on the recent apps list (task switcher) until the user interface shows up.  If the user swipes off the application from the recent task list, the Android Beacon Library uses an alarm to restart itself to look for beacons in the background within 5 minutes.

Comment: @davidgyoung Why not to use IntentService for it (just like for handling GCM messages)?

Comment: An IntentService is a good way to get a message from an *external* or system service like GCM.  When using the Android Beacon Library the beacon scanning service is bundled with your app, and runs as an internal service in the background.

Comment: It is mandatory to implement `BootstrapNotifier` on `Application` class only, wont it work the same way if 'BootstrapNotifier` is implemented on `Activity`?

Comment: No, it will not work on an Activity as an Activity's increase is not called until that activity is about to become visible.

Comment: Is this the same behavior that iOS exhibits where the app is woken-up automatically in presence of iBeacon? It appears that Android still has to do scanning all the time to detect any beacon and there is no mechanism for the OS to do it and notify when a beacon is discovered.

Comment: It works in a similar way to iOS, yes.  In the case of Android, the scanning code is bundled with the app, and at least that part of the app must be running to auto launch the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this was very painful but I finally managed to detect the beacons using the [Nearby Messages API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview).

1. First create a [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) project
2. Enable the "Nearby Messages API" for the project you just created
3. Create an API Key for this project, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started#step_3_get_an_api_key) and add it to the Manifest
4. Configure and register your beacons as described [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview); what I had to do was install the Android app, open it, select the project I just created, discover the beacon and register it with my app
5. You will have to attach a message to your beacon, to get it detected. I did this using the [Beacon Tools app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.location.beacon.beacontools), click the registered beacon, and tap on "Attachments"
6. Now you can follow the code sample [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/pub-sub#subscribe_to_messages) and it should detect your beacon

   ```
   Nearby.Messages.subscribe(googleApiClient, new MessageListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFound(Message message) {
           Log.i(TAG, "Found : " + message);
       }

       @Override
       public void onLost(Message message) {
           Log.i(TAG, "Lost : " + message);
       }
   }, new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
           .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
           .build());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This has been possible since the release of Google play services v8.4 SDK (December 2015).

See the following link for more:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-play-services-84-sdk-is-available_18.html